# Cygwin w/ MySQL SELECT: Command not found... Running external .sql file

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I am very new to Cygwin, but I've been using Windows Command Prompt to run my MySQL questions and process external MySQL queries with no issues.

I upgraded to Cgywin because it's just a nicer interface with a lot more options.

I am calling an external script here: E:/dir/test.sql .. and I would like to note this test.sql works perfect in Windows Command Prompt when I run the query the same way under the MySQL CLI. MySQL server is installed and running as expected.

```
$ \. E:/dir/test.sql
-bash: SELECT: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: ,: command not found
-bash: E:/dir/test.sql: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `concat'
-bash: E:/dir/test.sql: line 9: `INSERT(concat(b.geo_state, replace("b.mtr", ' ', ''), 
 '
```

After some research, I found if I run: $ which mysql, i get a linux like path: /usr/bin/mysql, and all I can think of is my mysql.exe is in a different directory that might be all the problem is.

But I do not know or cannot locate how to change the default Cygwin path for MySQL (if this is even the likely cause.).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that bash is trying to run your script, instead of mysql.

Try putting

```
#!/usr/bin/mysql
```

at the top of the script.

Still, I'd be surprised if that actually worked, because the normal way to run sql scripts in mysql, on Unixy systems at least, is piping them into mysql

```
mysql [options...] <test.sql
```

Note the "<" character.

I have very little experience with mysql on Windows, so I don't know how come it works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

first type in Cygwin terminal whether mysql is working fine or not?!

a. if correct copy your script to  /home

b. type

```
     cd /home
     mysql < test.sql
```

it will work sure try